# How to delete a tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

AFAIK, only moderators can delete a tag. In that case, how do we notify the moderators for unwanted/useless tags? Eg: mountain-identifying is a tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On SO, you normally [write a post on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172166/delete-the-dhtml-tag) (as you have) with the [feature-request](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) tag requesting that the tag is [burninated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/burninate-request) and if a moderator agree's they will delete it.

[image]

---

It also states that

> If the tag has 0 question associated with it, do not submit a tag
>   deletion request. Tags with no questions under them are automatically
>   deleted by the system within 24 hours and no action on the moderator's
>   part is required.

which implies, re-tagging the single question in this post will remove it.

Comment: Thank you. I have added the feature request tag. Hope it is take up by the moderators.

Answer (score 2):

All it takes to delete a tag is to remove it from all questions and then it will be automatically deleted. In the case of tags with lots of answers, it makes sense to ask on meta before retagging while if there are only one or two then one user can quickly delete it without boring everyone else to death.

The only time a moderator is needed to delete is when we are switching out tags. Changing [rope](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rope) to [ropes](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ropes) would require a regular user to remove it from all questions, wait 24 hours and then put [ropes](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ropes) back onto those questions. Changing [uk](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uk) to [united-kingdom](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-kingdom) would require retagging of all of the questions tagged with [uk](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uk).

In both of those cases, it would be better for a moderator to use their tools and avoid the retagging.

Comment: I'd say it's better to do it with mod tools if it's lets say 3 or more questions, as the questions wont get bumped that way.

Comment: @imsodin https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1206/%CC%B6m%CC%B6a%CC%B6y%CC%B6-%CC%B62%CC%B60%CC%B61%CC%B68%CC%B6-april-2019-tag-rename-requests ......

Comment: For changes like [tag:rope] to [tag:ropes], it is generally better to just create a tag synonym.