# Can a tag that has been deleted be re-created using the same name?

Tags: support, tags

I learned from [How to delete a tag?](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/456/how-to-delete-a-tag) that

> If the tag has 0 questions associated with it, do not submit a tag deletion request. Tags with no questions under them are automatically deleted by the system within 24 hours and no action on the moderator's part is required.

Though I could be wrong, it appears that this is happening to certain tags on our site. Since tag deletions don't have to be publicly requested or announced, for instance on meta, users won't necessarily know what happened until a tag we had previously seen here no longer exists.

I'd like to know whether or not we can ever re-create a tag with that same name. For instance, someone can choose to remove the [hiking](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hiking) tag from all existing questions. (This is not likely to happen since it's currently our most-used tag!) Within 24 hours, and with no action on the part of a moderator or any other official, the tag would be gone.

If someone with enough reputation to create tags thought the [hiking](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hiking) tag had merit, and attempted to create it,  would the system allow it? (Obviously the tag would not come with any description, so it would be like a clean slate.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless we blacklist a tag which to the best of my knowledge hasn’t happened on this site yet then it is possible to recreate a tag.

For instance someone could recreate the widgeteering tag if they wanted to but I highly doubt that would happen.

And yes I have deleted several tags recently including widgeteering

Comment: Thanks for responding so quickly! I assume blacklist means that for some reason a tag would be completely inappropriate or maybe detrimental to the site. If I'm wrong, please correct me. Otherwise, I have the information I need, and I appreciate it. I'm sorry about widgeteering though, I was really looking forward to learning how to do that!!