# ̶M̶a̶y̶ ̶2̶0̶1̶8̶ April 2019 tag rename requests

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I found a few more non-pluralized tags and so I am going to list them and their replacements again, and would also appreciate if a few other people would go over the list and the query I am using to pull the tags to see if I missed anything.

- [belay](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/belay)  -> belaying
- [bite](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bite) -> bites
- [bow](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bow) -> bows
- [camming-device](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/camming-device) -> camming-devices
- [canister-stove](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/canister-stove) -> canister-stoves
- [cleaning-fish](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cleaning-fish) -> fish-cleaning
- [climbing-grade](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/climbing-grade) -> climbing-grades
- [coconut-palm](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coconut-palm) -> coconut-palms
- [fiberglass-kayak](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fiberglass-kayak) -> fiberglass-kayaks
- [flashlight](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flashlight) -> flashlights
- [glacier](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/glacier) -> glaciers
- [helmet](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/helmet) -> helmets
- [headlamp](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/headlamp) -> headlamps
- [long-bow](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/long-bow) -> long-bows
- [midge](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/midge) -> midges
- [national-monument](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/national-monument) -> national-monuments
- [national-park](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/national-park) -> national-parks
- [rope](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rope) -> ropes
- [shotgun](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shotgun) -> shotguns
- [rattlesnake](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rattlesnake) -> rattlesnakes
- [slingshot](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/slingshot) -> slingshots

The query I am using to find these is,

```
SELECT TagName

FROM tags
WHERE tagname NOT LIKE '%s'
AND tagname NOT LIKE '%ing'
AND tagname NOT LIKE '%tion'
```

and it brings back quite a few false positives. I know I am missing some, and so am more than happy to have other people weigh in on this.

Comment: Why not just propose these as tag synonyms and then let regular high rep users take care of them (or at least make it easier on the mods).

Comment: @StrongBad because if regular users vote on synonyms it doesn't go through and update all the old ones while mods doing it will update all of them and there is no way for a regular user to fix the pluralization ones. Also ever since certain unnamed users have not logged in a good while, there has been very few flags to handle at least from what I can see