# Tag merge request: toilet-etiquette and human-waste

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms, tag-merge-request

I think we should merge the tags [toilet-etiquette](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/toilet-etiquette) and [human-waste](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/human-waste).

Although people might come up with (hypothetical) questions covered by one and not the other, the overlap is substantial and a single tag should suffice.

Comment: Do you just eat to add this one to the list here https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1206/8794. ?

Comment: @CharlieBrumbaugh Tag renaming and tag merging/synonyms are different things, aren't they?  (Not sure what "Do you just eat" means here, is this a typo / autocorrect error?)

Comment: I don’t know that it matters as we want a mod to do either last time I did put the merges in a separate section of the list. Also I think human waste is the tag we should keep

Comment: Agree on keeping human waste.  Toilet etiquette is too frou-frou for TGO.

Answer (score 1):

Done - I have merged and ensured the synonym will remain.